# How to store an XML file content into a std::string or CString, at compilation time?

Tags: c++, xml, stdstring

The XML contains symbols that the C++ may misinterpret (like the // in http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema)

I am wondering if you know about clean ways to include some hard-coded XML into a std::string or a CString, at compile time.

(in deed I'm trying to encode an .xsd file for validating some xml input, because I don't want to depend upon the presence or not of this xsd file, so I want it to be compiled in the binary)

Comment: The "//" sequence is not special in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const char* XML_STRING = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><Test></Test>";

std::string aTestXmlStr(XML_STRING);
```

Comment: Many thanx, you were completely right, the only problem was with the use of double quotation mark. That way it works just fine:

static const string strXsd = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\
<xs:schema xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">\
 <xs:element name=\"Configs\">\
  <xs:complexType>\
   <xs:sequence>\
    <xs:element name=\"Config\">\
     <xs:attribute name=\"UserName\" type=\"xs:string\" />\
     <xs:attribute name=\"ScreenPermutation\" type=\"xs:integer\" />\
    </xs:element>\
   </xs:sequence>\
  </xs:complexType>\
 </xs:element>\
</xs:schema>\
";